# Car runs worse since repair after shady dealer interaction

Tags: canada, consumer-protection, motor-vehicle, warranties, quebec

I got some spark plugs replaced on my car, which I got quoted cheaper than the cost of parts due to an error in the dealership's system.

The labour was supposed to be quoted for 3-4 hours plus the cost of the parts. During the day of the repair, I got a call from the dealer saying there was an error in their system and they asked me to meet them halfway, which I refused since  I already agreed to a price. They then told me they would finish the job and call me when the car was ready. (To me, this is a red flag, but what can I do about this)

When I got the second car, I made my way to the dealer got asked again if I would meet them halfway since they're losing money. I refused again.

I then got into my car and noticed a rattling when I started the car, but shrugged it off (I know I should not have). A week later, my engine is not running smoothly at all. I can barely get to highway speeds, it appears several cylinders are not firing. I brought the car back to this same dealer to get a diagnosis on the issue.

Now, I had a shady experience with them before and I do not trust them. However, I made the mistake to bring it back to them since they're the only dealer that can give me an appointment before my warranty ends (On June 1st or 3000km, whichever comes first).

What are my options if the situation gets worse due to a poor job from the dealership since I did not want to meet them halfway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to work it out with them if you can. I know they messed up more than once.

Also, since you said dealer and warranty, I am assuming you bought the car new. If that is so, you can call the manufacturer and they would most likely have another dealership fix it if the original one won't.

If you can't work it out, suing them for the cost of making your car work correctly again is about all the courts can really do for you.

Good Luck